# Keep margin of absolute positioned and centered div on window resize

Tags: css, margin, window-resize

I have few divs on my page, which serve as a containers. Here is a sample CSS code of one of the divs:

```
header {
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 153px;
    width: 97%;
    min-width: 1084.06px;
    margin: 15px auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; 
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

This is a centered container for my header. There are several other containers which I have styled simillar way (absolute, centered and width in %).

Problem is, when I resize the window, all these containers hit the left side of the browser window. I want to save some margin on particular window width. How can I achieve that?

P.S.  If I add `margin-left` it breaks my center position of the div

Comment: You can remove your width, and change left and right value to some percentages (for example 5%). Or you can use media queries (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Comment: Thanks @Armin, removing width and adding percentages to left and right values achieved what I wanted! I will also learn about media queries!

Answer (score 1):

You can use media queries, media queries are only applied on specific conditions, such as a specific width.

For example the following **background-color** rule won't apply for screens wider than **480px**:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  body {
    background-color: lightgreen;
  }
}
```

For more info about media queries see [this w3schools page](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Add another margin-right 
then straighten it out depending on what you use